# Какое общее правило, когда использовать try catch?

Tags: алгоритм, try-catch

На собеседовании мне задали вопрос, какое есть общее правило, когда делать try и catch.
Я ответил, когда есть работа с внешними ресурсами, где возникновение ошибки не зависит от программиста. Например, когда есть работа с файлами или БД (файл может не существовать, на диске может закончиться место, коннект к БД может не пройти)
Ответ оказался не полным.

Якобы есть какое-то правило, когда нужно использовать try catch

Сам я склоняюсь к тому, что правильный ответ: использовать try catch надо, когда нельзя обойтись проверками if/else
А что думаете вы? Какой правильный ответ?

Вопрос касается любого языка.

Comment: а язык не Java случайно?

Comment: @pavel, _Вопрос касается любого языка._

Comment: Не Java. Любой язык. (Хотя я знаю, что в Java, часто приходится обрабатывать, иначе компилятор не скомпилит)

Comment: @Grundy ну в каждом языке свои тараканы есть... В Java проверяемые исключения - отдельный вопрос мог быть. А дальше имхо code-style

Comment: Я закрыл как дубликат, потому что общий подход к использованию исключений в Java и в C# примерно один и тот же.

Answer (score 8):

Я не знаю, какой ответ хотели услышать от вас на собеседовании, и мне кажется, что стопроцентно верного критерия быть не может.

Моё мнение: нужно ловить исключение в том месте, где *вы знаете, что с ним делать*.

Поясню.

Допустим, у вас есть функция открытия файла, файла не нашлось, и она выбрасывает исключение. Что делать в этой точке?

Это важная операция, без информации из файла продолжать нельзя, так что нужно проинформировать пользователя и завершить программу? Или это файл конфигурации, которого в начале работы программы нету, и его нужно будет создать с данными по умолчанию?

В функции открытия файла вы этого не знаете. Поэтому исключение ловить не надо, дайте ему *пролететь* на более высокий уровень. А вот на уровне более крупноблочной логики, которая запустила операцию чтения конфигурации, вполне можно про приходу исключения при открытии файла отловить его и просто создать конфигурацию по умолчанию.

Такая одноуровневая схема может оказаться слишком простой, и вам придётся на пути перепаковывать исключение, добавляя в него смысла. Например, при чтении числа из строки произошло исключение из-за несоответствия формата. Вы в этой точке не знаете, фатальна ли эта проблема, и просто пропускаете исключение дальше. Логика более высокого уровня знает, что происходит операция чтения конфигурационных данных, которая почему-то завершилась с исключением. В этой точке логика программы имеет возможность решить, что игнорировать проблему нельзя, и она бросает более высокоуровневое исключение, которое означает «чтение конфигурации завершилось аварийно». Это исключение, в свою очередь, ловит бизнес-логика верхнего уровня, которая сообщает юзеру о потере конфигурационного файла и пересоздаёт его заново.

В любом случае, преждевременный отлов исключений на слишком «внутреннем» уровне вреден, потому что программа в такой точке обычно не может сделать ничего разумного.

Answer (score 7):

Вопрос именно так стоит? `try` и `catch`? Не исключения вообще?

Тогда - там, где возможна генерация исключения, которое может быть разумно обработано вашим кодом. Если исключение не может быть сгенерировано - `try/catch` ни к чему :) Если вы не можете его обработать - тоже нет смысла его ловить, лучше передать дальше.

Comment: try и catch, не исключения вообще.

Comment: Один мой знакомый сказал, что использовать try / catch нужно тогда, когда может возникнуть исключение времени выполнения. Мне этот ответ нравится, пока я считаю это правильным ответом.

Ваше дополнение "Если вы не можете его обработать - тоже нет смысла его ловить, лучше передать дальше.", мне тоже нравится

Comment: @Олег2 ответ "если может возникнуть" может и простой, но он в корне неверный. Смотрите - при любом создании объекта вы можете получить OutOfMemoryError. Еще пара исключений может возникнуть вообще в любой момент (по крайней мере в C# так, в Java скорее всего тоже). Значит ... ваш знакомый посоветовал вам использовать try/catch вообще всегда и везде.

Comment: @Олег2 Скажите, а что должен делать ваш try/catch в ситуации, когда вы *не можете* обработать исключение? Как он должен выглядеть?

Comment: @Harry тогда не надо делать try catch

Comment: @Олег2 Вот именно это я и написал в ответе :)